# 'git remote show <remote>' does not obey 'config push.default'

Tags: git

I needed to have a local branch pulling and pushing to a remote branch of a different name. The pull is setup automatically after cloning and fetching. But the push was a little harder. I wanted this:

```
git push <remote> <localBranch>:<remoteBranch>
```

without having to worry about the `local:remote` every time. I've got all that working thanks to [this blog post](http://longair.net/blog/2011/02/27/an-asymmetry-between-git-pull-and-git-push/).

So as the blog explains, I set my global config to use the 'upstream' option by default. e.g:

```
git config --global push.default upstream
```

And it correctly pushes the local branch to the remote branch with just `git push <remote>`.

But when I do a `git remote -v show <remote>` on a remote with the default master branch as the upstream, I get the following:

```
* remote <remote>
  Fetch URL: <giturl>
  Push  URL: <giturl>
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    myLocalBranch merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

Why does it still report the local 'master' branch as the source for pushing? It even says out of date (which it is if using the local 'master'). Except doing the `git push <remote>` results in `Everything up-to-date` so it is definetly using the `myLocalBranch` correctly.

Am I misunderstanding something? Is this a bug in the git remote show command? Or have I got my config into a weird state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the OP was under the false impression that the '`git remote`' was mentioning master as the branch to which `myLocalBranch` was pushing.

This isn't true: all that was displayed is that the local `master` is pushing to the remote `master` (probably set during the initial clone of the repo).

The `branch.myLocalBranch.merge` config specific to `myLocalBranch` isn't listed by the `git remote`.

Comment: I do want 'myLocalBranch' to push/pull to/from the remote 'master' branch. And it is doing that as far as I can tell. The issue I'm having is why does the `git remote show` tell me my local ref configured for git push is my local master branch when it is actually using 'myLocalBranch' correctly?

Comment: @Tyson: the global push policy is `matching` or  `simple` (depending on your Git version), and since there is both a local and a remote `master` branch, the `git remote show` command mentions that, because of that global policy, the local `master` is configured to push to the remote `master` (same name). Independently of that policy, your `myLocalBranch` has register an upstream branch (here the remote `master`).

Comment: But my global push policy is not matching or simple. As I said in my question, I have already changed it to upstream via `git config --global push.default upstream`.

Comment: @Tyson yes, my mistake: "upstream", but that doesn't change the fact that the master branch exists with the same name both locally and on the remote repo. That is why it is listed as pushing to master.

Comment: But that's incorrect! if I do a simple `git push` from myLocalBranch, it correctly follows `branch.myLocalBranch.remote=<remote>` and `branch.myLocalBranch.merge=refs/heads/master` and pushes myLocalBranch to <remote>.master. So why does `git remote show` list the wrong local ref?

Comment: @Tyson: what the `git remote` displays, according to your question is: `master pushes to master`: it doesn't say anything (directly at least) about `myLocalBranch` push. `master` has the remote `master` branch as upstream, certainly because the initial clone of your remote repo cloned the `master` branch. But again, this has no bearing on `myLocalBranch`, which has its own '`.merge`' settings making its push custom. And that custom push isn't listed by `git remote`.

Comment: Ahh ok got it, so both my local 'master' and 'myLocalBranch' push to remote.master, but `git remote show` only lists the 'master' one. Still somewhat misleading, especially because I currently have 'myLocalBranch' checked out. Perhaps `git remote show` should take into account the current checked out branch and list that if it is pushing to that remote.

Comment: @Tyson yes, git remote doesn't seem to list the `branch.myLocalBranch.merge` config. I have edited my answer to make that more visible.

Comment: Thanks Von. Could you edit your answer to remove your original answer, it is misleading as I wasn't asking about updating the remote upstream branch. Then I'll accept your answer. Cheers.